# How Can I Write a Method that References the Object that is Calling it?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, methods, this

I'm trying to make a program that prints out the three numbers you input and then outputs the average of those numbers. After creating the methods needed, when I compiled the code, there were errors when using the methods with `scores`. I'm not sure how I can reference `scores` when calling `mPrint()` or `average()` on it.

When the code is compiled, it throws errors at the lines where `scores.mPrint(3);` and `scores.average();` are. Those errors are:
`The method` (method here) `is undefined for the type ArrayList<Double>`.

I imported: java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Scanner

```
public class OOPtraining {

ArrayList<Double> scores = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void mPrint(Integer prints) {

    for (Integer i =0;i<prints; i++) {
        System.out.println(scores.get(i));
    }

}

public void average() {

    double divi = scores.get(0)+scores.get(1)+scores.get(2);
    System.out.println(divi/3);

}

public void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Double> scores = new ArrayList<Double>();

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);


    // down here is where I input the scores and then add them to "scores"
    System.out.println("Enter a score: ");
    double score1 = reader.nextDouble();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Type a double-type number:");
        try {
            score1 = Double.parseDouble(reader.next());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    scores.add(score1);


    System.out.println("Enter another score: ");
    double score2 = reader.nextDouble();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Type a double-type number:");
        try {
            score2 = Double.parseDouble(reader.next());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    scores.add(score2);


    System.out.println("Enter another score: ");
    double score3 = reader.nextDouble();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Type a double-type number:");
        try {
            score3 = Double.parseDouble(reader.next());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    scores.add(score3);
    //here is where I stop adding the scores to "scores"


    scores.mPrint(3);
    scores.average();


    }
}
```

Comment: what is in get(...) ?

Comment: In what way does it seem to be incorrect?

Comment: Please tell us what you expect this to do. It makes no sense as it is.

Comment: It's very unclear your question, be more explicit please

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic in the question above, but what I want to know is how to refer to the ArrayList that the method would be called upon if it is called (in this case, `scores`) when I'm creating a method.

Comment: As I noted in my answer below @AlexKnue you need to move your 'scores' variable to the class level rather than local to the main method. Then you'll be able to refer to this,scores.get(i) or whatever you want. You'll have some other issues but that should get your started.

Comment: @AndrewAitken Alas, doing this leaves only two compilation errors. Those two are situated at `scores.mPrint(3);` and `scores.Average();`. The error that's thrown (by Eclipse) is "The method mPrint()/Average() is undefined for the type ArrayList<Double>".

Comment: @AlexKnue once it's class level variable you should still initialise it in your main method, then you can access is calling 'this.scores', not just 'scores'.

The 2 methods which are failing are because they are indeed accessed by this.mPrint(3) and this.Average() as they are methods of the class OOPtraining which is what 'this' refers to. 

You will probably get more errors, I'm just trying to explain the scope of your variables really.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.get(i)
```

This will fail compilation because the class you've declared does not have a get method. It's very unclear what exactly you're trying to do though.

I see what you're trying to do now, you're trying to access a member variable of your class, 'this' refers to the class you're in OOPTraining. What you're trying to do is access the scores ArrayList. For you to be able to do that scores would have to be a class variable and not a local variable in your main method. Have a look at that and that should get you started.

Comment: I recently added the rest of the code for clarification. I didn't think the answerers needed the rest of it but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some method named get() in same class where you are trying to call this.get(int)
Otherwise it will not work.
i think you are working with list ,and forgotten to extend it

Comment: I recently practiced with methods, ArrayLists, and HashMaps on Codecademy and I'm not completely sure how to use "this", as I wasn't entirely exposed to it.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to some instance of your class `OOPtraining`. `this.get(0)` invokes the `get()` method on your class `OOPtraining` and passes `0` as the first and only argument to that method.

The problem is that your class `OOPtraining` *doesn't have* a `get()` method. You either need to add a `get()` method to `OOPtraining` or, more likely, figure out what you want `get()` to be invoked on and provide an instance of that class. Then the code will look like `myList.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If `this.get(i)` fails then there are 2 mistakes you might have made.

First, your class might not have a method with name `get`. So to correct the error do define the `get` method in your class.

Secondly, if you do have a `get` method you probably might have defined it with the `static` key word. In this case remove the `static` key word from the method's definition. Another solution, will be to replace the `this` keyword by your class name. Static methods are independent of objects, so the can be called without even constructing one.

Comment: How does `static` affect my code depending if I use it or not?

Comment: I just edited my answer, you can search more on that.